# Azure pipelines errors out in Download Artifacts task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, dynatrace

I am creating a pipeline in Azure DevOps pipelines that deploys out to an environment. It works in other VMs that I have just one specific VM it errors out in the javascript for the downloading artifact.

Here is the current code, I removed the actual deployment step but I still get the same error

```
  displayName: Deploy Test Environment
  jobs:
    - deployment: deploy_test
      displayName: Deploy Test
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/Test'))
      environment: 
        name: msptst
        resourceType: virtualMachine
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - template: templates\azure-test-deployment-template.yml
```

This is from the pipeline yaml, the next one is from the template in the deployment step

```
  - task: ExtractFiles@1
    inputs:
      archiveFilePatterns: '$(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/**/*.zip'
      destinationFolder: '$(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/ExtractedArtifact'
      cleanDestinationFolder: false
      overwriteExistingFiles: true
  - script: DIR "$(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)" /S
    continueOnError: true
```

Here is the error that I am getting.

```
C:\PROGRA~2\DYNATR~1\oneagent\agent\bin\125121~1.202\any\nodejs\nodejsagent.js:2611
  const e = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8), d = 2 ** 32;
                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at module.js:676:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'E:\azagent\A1\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"E:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.178.0\main.js"'.
Finishing: Download Artifact
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, from the error output, seems issue comes from the code of [this product](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/setup-and-configuration/dynatrace-oneagent#tabgroup--technology-support--cloud-platforms). How do you set up the agent on your side? If only this agent has issue, I suggest you to reinstall, re-config the agent and run the agent and then check whether the issue still exists.

Comment: And by the way, the definition you provided is not about download artifact. What is the task type? Download pipeline artifact or download build artifact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the new agent of Dynatrace, we also got this error. the **DownloadArtirfacts** task using very old node version (6) and the Dynatrace agent doesn't like it.

To resolve it you have 2 options:

1. Go to the agent folder `C:\azagent\1\externals` and copy from `node10` folder the node.exe (in `bin` folder) to the `node` folder (or rename both folders).
2. Update DownloadArtirfacts task to use `node10` folder, you need to get the task source code (exist in `C:\azagent\1\_work\_tasks`), change it in the `task.json` & `task.loc.json` and push it back with `tfx-cli`.